# background image sideshow for Konsole/terminal

Tags: command-line, desktop-background, konsole

Hey I am wondering if there is a way to point Konsole to a folder of images and make them a sideshow that switches every moment or so.

New to this so thanks for the help ^.^!!!

Comment: I don't think it's possible, *(though I didn't try a gif or video file, it could work, but could lag as well)*, but you could make a feature request. Or you [could use terminology](https://www.enlightenment.org/about-terminology) instead. It's a terminal of Enlightement DE, and accordingly to description does support even video files. But I should warn, I don't know which version would be in repository of your version of Ubuntu. The latest is 0.9.1.

Comment: Sounds like a great feature request though!

Answer (score 2):

No. You can not (at least until this answer writing, September 2016) . After exploring every options in Konsole, I found no option to set image slideshow for Konsole. But you can set a static background.

To do so: **Settings** -> **Edit Current Profile** -> **Appearance** Tab -> **Edit** button. There you can set a Background Image.